# Search a file in a directory using MS DOS

Tags: dos

How can I search a directory and its sub directories for a file and display the file name and its created time in a neat format.

I tried `dir sam.csv /b /s /a-d`

But does't work.

The output should look like

```
c:\Data\Sam.txt 10/10/2012 10.00 AM

c:\Data\1\Sam.txt 11/10/2012 10.00 AM

c:\Data\2\Sam.txt 12/10/2012 10.00 AM
```

Or can I do the same in a for loop?

Comment: What's wrong with the output? Can you tell us what it should look like? Perhaps this might be better of SuperUser.com

Comment: @PreetSangha :I have now included the expected output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f %f in ('dir sam.txt /s/b') do @echo %f  %~tf
```

This is it running.

```
C:\data>for /f %f in ('dir sam.txt /s/b') do @echo %f  %~tf
C:\data\Sam.txt  26/10/2012 10:49 a.m.
C:\data\1\Sam.txt  26/10/2012 10:49 a.m.
C:\data\2\Sam.txt  26/10/2012 10:49 a.m.
```

You can get more [help on the FOR command](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfor.php) using ***help for*** at the command prompt

Answer (score 1):

`dir sam.csv /s /4` shows what you asked in the question. If there is something else, please add it to your question.

Comment: I need it as a neat list. I do not want all the other directory information. I just need the full file name and the created time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The /b option is stripping out the date information.  You can get some great DOS syntax help here:

http://www.computerhope.com/msdos.htm

Comment: I used /b, so that I can exclude all other information, which I do not need. But I need datetime, which I do not know.